# creating Github pull requests on behalf of users on a specific repository

Tags: github, pull-request, github-app

I am creating a collaborative database using a GitHub repo. I own a GitHub repository and want users to add files using a specific format, so I would like to create pull requests on their behalf. Is there a way to do so less "intrusive" than using GitHub apps?

I don't want to create the pull request using a dedicated GitHub account, because I want users to take ownership of their contributions and leverage the full potential of GitHub.

Comment: So, you want these users to have their own github accounts?  Then this is just a normal pull request,  Git has good instructions on their web site for doing that, either on their web site or through command line.

Comment: You could trigger creating PRs following the pattern you want by way of Actions triggered by the creation of, for example, an issue? We'd need more details about what goes into a PR, though. Where do the files come from?

Comment: I just want them to fill an input text on a webpage, then my server would convert it to a file, create a commit and push it to the public repo using the credentials/token of the user